# rewrite nginx 2 parameters

Tags: nginx, php, rewrite

```
server {

listen 127.0.0.1:80;
server_name ap5 www.ap5;

root home/ap5/public_html;

index index.php index.html;

log_not_found off;
access_log logs/ap5-access.log;
error_log logs/error.log error;
charset utf-8;

location ~ /\. { deny all; }
location = /favicon.ico { }
location = /robots.txt { }

     location ~ \.php$ {


        if (!-e $document_root$document_uri){return 404;}
        fastcgi_pass ap5:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        include fastcgi_params;

    }



location / {
try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ @extensionless-php;
index index.html index.htm index.php;


      rewrite ^/users/([a-z0-9\-]+)?$ /users.php?action=$1 last;
      rewrite ^/users/([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)?$ /users.php?action=$1&role=$2" last;
```

}

location @extensionless-php {

```
rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
```

}

}

Fist of all I am new to Nginx so not sure if I did it right.
I have got following rewrite in nginx  done, I remove the php extention and then I parse the request. The fist request is working fine where I have one parameter, the other request with 2 parameters is a problme as the page redirects always to 404 page, but I dont know why. Can somebody help on this? thank you for help

```
Here are the 2 requests

  rewrite ^/users/([a-z0-9\-]+)?$ /users.php?action=$1 last;
  rewrite ^/users/([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)?$ /users.php?action=$1&role=$2" last;
```

Dany

Comment: Which are exactly the "first" and "second" requests? Clear examples please.

Comment: Hi Tero, please see below location / {
try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ @extensionless-php;
index index.html index.htm index.php;


      rewrite ^/users/([a-z0-9\-]+)?$ /users.php?action=$1 last;
      rewrite ^/users/([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)?$ /users.php?action=$1&role=$2" last;

Comment: Those are not requests, those are configuration lines.

Comment: sorry was referring to rewrite rules, maybe I haven't express properly

Comment: Well, still we need examples of the actual requests, so we can try to find out what goes wrong there.

Comment: can you let me know what you would consider under request, I have a page on which I have link to users.php?action=$1&role=$2, so when I click on the link a given action filter will be performed and displays the role based on link

Comment: A concrete URL to a page that fails and that works.

Comment: I have it set up on my local server so there is no external url link

Comment: Well, it is still quite impossible to answer the question when there is no example of a working and failing request...